# Animation for images working on scroll up

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

This is my HTML

```
<section class="labs-hero__top-container sprinter-lab__common-bg">
    <div class="labs-hero__container ">
        <picture class="labs-hero__label">
            <source media="(min-width: 1100px)" srcset="./assets/images/label.png">
            
            <img src="./assets/images/label.png" />
          </picture>
        <!-- <h1 class="labs-hero__heading">voluptatem accusantium doloremque</h1> -->
        <div class="labs-hero__image labs-hero__image--hide animate__animated"></div>
        <div class="labs-hero__image--vans labs-hero__image--hide labs-hero__image--fade-out"></div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="label-section__main-container">
        <picture class="label-section__image-label">
            <source media="(min-width: 1100px)" srcset="./assets/images/label-labs.png">
                
            <img src="./assets/images/label-labs.png" />
        </picture>
</section>
<section class="sprinter-lab__common-bg solid">
    <div class="main-animation__container">
        <div class="main-animation__frame"></div>
        <div class="main-animation__slider">
            <picture class="main-animation__slider-image">
                <source media="(min-width: 1100px)" srcset="./assets/images/front.png">    
                <img src="./assets/images/front.png" />
            </picture>
            <div class="main-animation__content">
                <h2 class="main-animation__slider-heading">voluptatem accusantium doloremque</h2>
                <p class="main-animation__slider-desc">TSed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="sprinter-lab__common-bg solid">
    <div class="main-animation__container">
        <div class="main-animation__slider">
            <div class="main-animation__content">
                <h2 class="main-animation__slider-heading">from dream to drive</h2>
                <p class="main-animation__slider-desc">TSed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab.</p>
            </div>
            <picture class="main-animation__slider-image">
                <source media="(min-width: 1100px)" srcset="./assets/images/front.png">    
                <img src="./assets/images/front.png" />
            </picture>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="labs-hero sprinter-lab__common-bg solid">
    <div class="labs-hero__text-container">
        <image src='assets/images/MSV-logo.png'/>
        <p class="labs-hero__sub-heading">de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum</p>
        <h2 class="labs-hero__title">de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum</h2>
        <p class="labs-hero__description">TSed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab.</p>
        <button class="labs-hero__button">de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum</button>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="sprinter-lab__common-bg solid">
    <div class="main-animation__container">
        <div class="main-animation__slider">
            <div class="main-animation__content">
                <h2 class="main-animation__slider-heading">Sed ut perspiciatis</h2>
                <p class="main-animation__slider-desc">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
            </div>
            <picture class="main-animation__slider-image">
                <source media="(min-width: 1100px)" srcset="./assets/images/front.png">    
                <img src="./assets/images/front.png" />
            </picture>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This the scss code I have written where I have the animation for before and after image.

```
  .labs-hero {
  &__text-container {
width: 81.25%;
max-width: 1170px;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
padding-top: 30px;
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  padding: 50px 20px;
  height:unset;
}
&.animation{
  &::before {
    content: "";
    background: url("/assets/images/football-desktop.png") no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    // height:100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-25%);
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    animation: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: football;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      content: "";
      background: url("/assets/images/football-image.png") no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: contain;
      animation: none;
      transform: translateY(0);
      position: unset;
      margin-bottom: 81px;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 860px) {
      background-size: 130%;
      z-index:-1;
    }
  }

  &::after {
    content: "";
    background: url("/assets/images/wrench-desktop.png") no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    right: -6%;
    transform: translateY(-51%);
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    display: flex;
    background-position: right;
    margin-top: 75px;
    z-index: 1;
    animation: 3s;
    animation-name: wrench;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      width: 100%;
      height: 273px;
      transform: translate(12%, -20%);
      animation: none;
      content: "";
      background: url("/assets/images/Wrench-mb.png") no-repeat;
      position: unset;
      margin-top: 131px;
      right: 0%;
      background-position: right;
      display: flex;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 946px) {
      margin-top: 35px;
      width:50%;
      // z-index:-1;
    }
  }
}
&.up-animation{
  &::before {
    content: "";
    background: url("/assets/images/football-desktop.png") no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    // height:100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    // transform: translateY(-25%);
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    animation: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: football-up;
    // animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      content: "";
      background: url("/assets/images/football-image.png") no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: contain;
      animation: none;
      transform: translateY(0);
      position: unset;
      margin-bottom: 81px;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 860px) {
      background-size: 130%;
      z-index:-1;
    }
  }

  &::after {
    content: "";
    background: url("/assets/images/wrench-desktop.png") no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    right: -6%;
    transform: translateY(-51%);
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    display: flex;
    background-position: right;
    margin-top: 75px;
    z-index: 1;
    animation: 3s;
    animation-name: wrench-up;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      width: 100%;
      height: 273px;
      transform: translate(12%, -20%);
      animation: none;
      content: "";
      background: url("/assets/images/Wrench-mb.png") no-repeat;
      position: unset;
      margin-top: 131px;
      right: 0%;
      background-position: right;
      display: flex;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 946px) {
      margin-top: 35px;
      width:50%;
      // z-index:-1;
    }
  }
}

   }

  }

 @keyframes football {
from {
    top: 10px;
    left:-15%;
    }
to {
    top: 350px;
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    left:-10%;
    }
    }

 @keyframes wrench {
    to {
    top: -280px;
    transform: rotate(-40deg);
    }
    from {
    top: 70px;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
   }

 @keyframes football-up {
   from {
  top: 350px;
  left:-15%;
  }
  to {
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  left:-10%;
  }
  }

 @keyframes wrench-up {
   to {
  top: 280px;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
  }
  from {
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
 }
```

This is my javascript code to apply animation on scroll up and scroll down but the animation for before and after image is not getting applied on scroll up.

```
    function scrollTrigger(selector, options = {}) {
      let els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
       els = Array.from(els);
        els.forEach((el) => {
        addObserver(el, options);
      });
     }

      function addObserver(el, options) {
         if (!("IntersectionObserver" in window)) {
           if (options.cb) {
             options.cb(el);
            } else {
             entry.target.classList.add("active");
              setTimeout(() => {
             entry.target.classList.remove("active");
             }, 1000);
            }
            return;
         }

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        if (options.cb) {
          options.cb(el);
        } else {
          entry.target.classList.add("active");
        }
        // observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        console.log("root entry",entry);
      } else if (entry.boundingClientRect.y < entry.rootBounds.y) {
          console.log("bound",entry.boundingClientRect.y)
          console.log("root",entry.rootBounds.y)
          console.log('hello')
        // Added condition for scrolling from bottom to top
        if (options.upCb) {
          options.upCb(el);
        } else {
          entry.target.classList.add("up-active");
        }
        // observer.unobserve(entry.target);
      }
    });
  },
  options
);
     observer.observe(el);
     }

    scrollTrigger('.labs-section-host__image-container',{cb:(el) =>{
      el.classList.add('host-animation')
      },threshold:0.5})

     scrollTrigger('.labs-section-host__image-container--right-variation',{cb:(el) =>{
      el.classList.add('host-animation')
      },threshold:0.5})

      // Example usage:
       scrollTrigger(".labs-hero__text-container", {
         cb: (el) => {
          el.classList.add("animation");
         },
         upCb: (el) => {
         el.classList.add("up-animation");
         },
        threshold: 0.5,
      });
```

I have 2 images that is in before and after pseudo elements. The before element is in the left side of the page and after image is in right side of the page. Now when I'm trying to scroll down animation for these 2 images are coming up like before image is sliding down and after image is sliding up. but when I scroll up again the animation should come in reverse order Like the before image should move on the top and after image should move down. But according to my logic the scroll up animation is not coming up.